# Publishing an Pypi Package getting an error in Read the Data within Package Script

Tags: python, pypi

I was trying to publish a Pypi Package to retrieve the Indian Abbreviation and have the data in the JSON format. Also given the path an folder structure as suggested in Stack overflow but still facing the same issue. Attached is the image for the reference of folder Structure and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzbc2.png)
The code follows as

```py
json_file_path=pkg_resources.resource_filename('Abbre','my_data/output_2.json')
    with open (json_file_path,'r')as f:
        loaded_dict=json.load(f)
        arr1=arr.lower().strip()
        #print(loaded_dict)

    empty_list=[]
    for i,j in loaded_dict.items():
        if i==arr1:
                empty_list.append(j)
                print(empty_list)
                break

        else:
            print(" The data is not available")
            break
```

Attached the error for your reference

```py
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_54872\4275681862.py in <module>
      1 import Abbre
----> 2 Abbre.Abbreviation('nlc')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Abbre.py in Abbreviation(arr)
      6         will give an output of list Life Insurance of corporation
      7         """
----> 8     with open ('Abbre\output_2.json','r')as f:
      9         loaded_dict=json.load(f)
     10         arr1=arr.lower().strip()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Abbre\\output_2.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that data file is not included in your package. If you use setuptools, according to the [document](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html), you have 2 choices:

1. create a `MANIFEST.in` file in your project root like:

```
include Abbre/output_2.json
```

2. add this to `setup.py`:

```py
    package_dir={"": "."},
    package_data={"Abbre": ["output_2.json"]},
```

Comment: I have given the setup.py in this case

long_description=long_description,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'Abbre': ['my_data/*']},
    include_package_data=True,
    name='Abbre',
    version='0.5',
    classifiers = [
  'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
  'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
  'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
], package_dir={'': 'Abbre/src'} ,
py_modules=["Abbre"],  # Name of the python package

Comment: I am still facing the issue and now after installing the published not able to import Abbre. Can you help me  in this